# Send a POST request on Windows 8 metro App with C#

Tags: c#, windows, windows-8, windows-8.1

I try to make a POST request for a long time with C# but it never works.
The statusCode from the server is 200 so it seems to work but the response I get is an "AccessDenied". The HTTP header seems to be the error.
The POST request made on JS works great but not the one on C#.
Here is the request :

```
string resourceAddress = " ... ";
try
{
     HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();  
     var content = new List<KeyValuePair <string,string>>
     {
       new KeyValuePair<string,string>(" ... "," ... "),
         ...
     };

     HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(resourceAddress, new FormUrlEncodedContent(content));
     response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
     var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); 
}

catch (HttpRequestException hre)   
{
      Debug.WriteLine(hre.ToString());
}

catch (Exception ex)   
{
      Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
}
```

Did I miss something ?
Does windows 8 with C# request modify or add something into the header ?

On Android I use this code :

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(urlWebSiteHTTPRequest);

try
{           
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("... ","... "));
    ....
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

    response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    entity = response.getEntity();
    responseText = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
}   
catch (ClientProtocolException e) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
} 
catch (IOException e) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
}
```

Comment: What is happening exactly? Are you getting an exception?

Comment: Does the server require authentication?

Comment: Can you provide NetMon or Fiddler traces?

Comment: Yes the server requires an authentification. I didn't add the parameter but they are working. I use the same parameter for other OS and it is working. I forgot to add that. I didn't get an exception. I get a response from the server but I receive an "AccessDenied" message. I checked the necessary parameter on the manifest and I added internet with client and server.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use NetMon or Fiddler.

Comment: Do you perform authentication step? In case if you do, do you use instance of `HttpClientHandler` with initialized `CookieContainer`? Most probably server requires presence of cookies. For example, some servers require presence of session cookie (ex:`JSESSIONID`) before you can authenticate. So you need to first send `GET` request, save the cookies from response and use them for `POST` request. That's what can be handled by `HttpClientHandler`.

Comment: No I don't perform an authentication step. I don't need it. I only send all my parameter on a POST request and the server respond by sending be an address to connect the user

Comment: Other OS - what kind of? Do you use the same code?

Comment: Android, iOS and ChromeOS. I don't use exactly the same code but the parameters are the same and the steps are the same.

Comment: I have updated my post and I added the code I use on Android

Answer (score 0):

I think the header is not properly formatted. Try using this  simple tool. You will be able to use it to debug http request messages and actually see the data and errors the server sends back. http://www.telerik.com/fiddler. Go to the composer tab to test request messages. Also make sure that your Authorization username:password are base64 encoded. That always seems to be the problem in most cases.

Best of Luck.

Comment: OP clearly [stated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23252569/send-a-post-request-on-windows-8-metro-app-with-c-sharp#comment35581388_23252569) that he cannot use Fiddler